# Removing selected elements from array of associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have the following array of associative arrays.

```
$result = array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'name' => 'Luke',
        'id_number' => '1111',
        'address' => '1544addr',
        'time_here' => '2014-04-12 13:07:08'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'name' => 'Sam',
        'id_number' => '2222',
        'address' => '1584addr',
        'time_here' => '2014-04-12 14:15:26'
```

I want to remove selected elements from this array such that it will look like this;

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'name' => 'Luke',
        'id_number' => '1111'
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'name' => 'Sam',
        'id_number' => '2222',
```

This is the code I wrote;

```
    foreach($result as $value) 
    {            
        unset($value('address')  );
        unset($value('time_here')  );
    }
```

When I run the code, Apache web server crashed.

Can the smarter members point out what did I do wrong? Thank you very much.

Comment: Your array notation is wrong. You need to use `[]` See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array notation is wrong, use this;

```
$finalResult = array();
foreach($result as $value) 
{            
    unset($value['address']  );
    unset($value['time_here']  );
    $finalResult[] = $value;
}
```

Here is a working demo: **[Demo](http://ideone.com/LLizEx)**

Comment: Thanks! I have one more problem. How do I store the truncated array to $result? The answer removes the element from $value, not $result.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23235855/filtering-selected-elements-from-array-of-associative-arrays

This time, I would like to filter selected elements and not remove them. This is more tricky. I don't even know what function to start with. At least, for removal, one can use unset(). Would you be able to help?

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not accessing array correctly. Use square bracket insted of round brackets :

```
foreach($result as $value) 
    {            
        unset($value['address']  );
        unset($value['time_here']  );
    }
```

Comment: It would be better, check already answered ones before posting your answer

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL Maybe you posted while i was typing. But anyways I would delete my answer so that you are the one who gets all the upvote :) Is that OK?